# reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.io.IOException: Connection closed prematurely

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have instance variable sWebClient like this (in manager class)

```
private WebClient sWebClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(getClientConnector()).build();
```

Expection is thrown in below code (This code is in one method inside manager class)

```
String response = sWebClient
            .mutate()
            .build()
            .post()
            .uri(url)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(sb.toString()))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
```

Exception

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.io.IOException: Connection closed prematurely
at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:326)
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:91)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1175)
```

We were using `RestTemplate` and `AsyncRestTemplate` earlier, that was also causing issue "Connection_Reset". Now We change all the codes to Reactive spring API, and we are getting the same type of error. And this is only happening on production. No problem in any qa env. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Useful link - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15972

Comment: What's the server responding? Is it closing the connection? Is there a proxy involved? Could you provide the HTTP request and response headers+body? Which version of Spring Framework and Reactor Netty are you using? I'm not sure the link you're providing in the comments is really relevant here.